# Jest: Ignoring a dependency

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

Currently I have a Mixin that is called on `mounted()` hook in my Vue Component:

**Component file:**

```
mixins: [testMixin],
mounted () {
  this.getMixin()
}
```

**Mixin (`testMixin`) file:**

```
// Test fails at the import because of `SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier`
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import isEmpty from 'lodash.isempty';


import DependencyThatImportsLodash from ''

export default {
  created () {
    this.getMixin()
  },
}
```

I have tried:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Component, {
  localVue,
  mocks: {
    getMixin: () => {}
  }
})
```

and

```
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.mixin(testMixin)
```

But I still get the lodash error, how can I get past it? Thanks

**This is my `jest.config.js`**

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue', 'json'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest'
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '/vendors/'
  ]
}
```